# Use Chart.js draw method as Typescript arrow function

Tags: typescript, chart.js

I am using Chart.js draw function to modify a line chart, below is the sample code-

```
 Chart.controllers.line = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
        draw: function() {
          const ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
          ctx.save();
          ctx.shadowColor = '#aefdda';
          ctx.shadowBlur = 7;
          ctx.shadowOffsetX = 1;
          ctx.shadowOffsetY = 3;
          ctx.stroke();
          draw.apply(this, arguments);
          ctx.restore();
        },
      });
```

But the problem is as per eslint rule this warning appearing **warning  Unexpected unnamed method 'draw'** and i need to convert it to an arrow function.But i cant use **this and arguments** inside an arrow function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ES6 shorter syntax for method definitions on objects initializers.

```js
 Chart.controllers.line = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
        draw () {
          const ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
```

If you use lower version of js, you can:

```js
 Chart.controllers.line = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
        draw: function draw () {
          const ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
```

You can check how ES6 syntax is converted to older js with babel: [interactive example](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MICwhgTgLgdAxgewHZQggNugphAzjdASySwAIBeU0SWRFNTHfIkmLADyiyQBMAKAN4AoUqLGieEMAHdSfAJSlh4laTq4oaqOwqkoIQvjjho8E7W0BuEatIBfIXflA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.9.0&externalPlugins=)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you do need to convert it to an arrow function. Try this style of object literal method declaration:

```
Chart.controllers.line = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  draw() {
    //...
  }
})
```

[See examples of good usage of the `func-names` rule here.](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names)